# How to get all 6 neighborhood cell ids on Android

Tags: android, localization, cellid

Is there any API that will give me those 6 neighborhood cell ids on Android, or shall I try to send AT commands to the Android modem.

If someone could explain that to me I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `android.telephony.TelephonyManager` and `getNeighboringCellInfo()`.